# How to modify positions of a list that don't exist?

Tags: python

How can I fill the 10th position of a list when it is empty?

Comment: You cannot address a position that doesn't exist yet in a list. However, if the size of the list is constant, you could create a list filled with `None`, and then update as needed. Or you could use a dictionary to simulate a sparse list, where you'd have key=position, value=value.

Comment: Use a dictionary instead? otherwise just `append` e.g. `-1` 10-1 times.

Comment: You can create a list of 10 `None` with `[None] * 10`

Comment: @peer `[-1] * 10` is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Python lists are not sparse.

However, you could use a dict with integer keys:

```
>>> faux_list = {10: 'foo'}
>>> faux_list[10]
'foo'
```

Or you could fill a list with dummy data, like in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63094414/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

I could initialize the list as

```
[-1 for _ in range(11)]
```

If I cannot fill the array with -1, then

```
[None for _ in range(11)]
```

or

```
[np.nan for _ in range(11)]
```

or

```
[float('inf') for _ in range(11)]
```